# convert a corpus of text with strings already wrapped in quotes and separated by linebreaks into just individual strings in a single list?

Tags: python, string, list, quotes

So a friend thought they would be super helpful by putting a long list of individual words into quotes separated by linebreaks. I ultimately need these to all be individual strings put into a list and without their line breaks.

New to python so maybe there is something easy I am missing??

I have tried using splitlines(), but it doesn't play nice with a multi line string. And when I don't use a multi line string, I don't know of a way to get all my words on one line, which is the problem to begin with.

```
food = '''
'apple'
'hot cakes'
'hot dogs'
'pie'
'watermelon'
'''

print(food.splitlines())
```

What the above code actually gives me is:

```
['', "'apple'", "'hot cakes'", "'hot dogs'", "'pie'", "'watermelon'"]
```

But what I WANT it to give me is:

```
['apple', 'hot cakes', 'hot dogs'...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` to get rid of quotes and use `splitlines` and get rid of the first line element (empty string):

```
print(food.replace("'",'').splitlines()[1:])
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'hot cakes', 'hot dogs', 'pie', 'watermelon']
```

Comment: Thanks that was super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python list comprehension as follows:

```
>>> food = '''
... 'apple'
... 'hot cakes'
... 'hot dogs'
... 'pie'
... 'watermelon'
... '''
>>> [x.replace("'", '') for x in food.splitlines() if x]
['apple', 'hot cakes', 'hot dogs', 'pie', 'watermelon']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close overall with `splitlines()`. There's two primary issues that you have with `splitlines()`. The first is that you're getting empty strings where there is no word on a line. The second is that you're still left with the quotes. The snippet below solves both issues:

```
food_split = [word.replace("'", '') for word in food.splitlines() if word.strip()]
```

This is roughly equivalent to (but much faster than):

```
food_split = []
for word in food.splitlines():
    if word.strip(): # check if the word is empty
        food_split.append(word.replace("'", ''))  # replace quotes with empty string
```

`if word.strip()` ensures that any blank lines with only whitespace are ignored, while `word.replace("'", '')` replaces the extra single quotes with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks this was also helpful. I am learning rapidly that there are million ways to solve a problem in python, so it's cool to see so many different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

```
print([x.strip("'") for x in food.splitlines() if x])
```

Use strip() inside list comprehension